# Regarding evaluation order

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

```
multiply :: Int -> Int -> Int 
multiply a b = a * b 

minus :: Int -> Int -> Int 
minus a b = a - b 

minus2 :: Int -> Int -> Int 
minus2 a b = b – a


minus2 (multiply (minus 3 5) 7) 9
minus2 ((minus 3 5) * 7) 9
9 - ((minus 3 5) * 7)
9 - ((3 - 5) * 7)
9 - ((-2) * 7)
9 - (-14)
23
```

Running the line `minus2 (multiply (minus 3 5) 7) 9`
Do I have the correct order of evaluation that Haskell would use?

Still new with functional programming so I'm not sure if I have the "lazy evaluation" process correct.

Comment: It doesn't matter what order its evaluated in, it's going to come out with the same answer.

Comment: yes, but I'm still required to show the order of evaluation for my work

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're required to show?  What's the exact wording of the assignment as it pertains to showing the order of evaluation?

Comment: The answer to the only direct question you asked is "No, you do not have the correct order of evaluation.". I'm not sure I'm comfortable writing down the correct order; could you please confirm that your course's rules on collaboration are okay with what you're doing here on SO? Or, more to the point: why are you asking here instead of asking your teacher('s assistant)?

Comment: You mention "the correct order of evaluation that Haskell would use", but there's no mandated order by Haskell, only a mandated (lazy) semantics. Probably you intend to use the so-called "normal evaluation order", which is one way to ensure lazy semantics. Even in such case, `x - y` could evaluate `x` before `y`, or in the other order. Maybe you are assuming left-to-right on arithmetic operators (?) It depends on what your course stated.

Answer (score 3):

You can test your hypothesis by replacing subexpressions by `(error "x")`, `(error "y")`, etc. Whichever error is evaluated first is the one to show up when you run the expression.

Answer (score 0):

To the point, evaluation can proceed in any order the compiler wants it to, as long as it gets the correct answer. For example, it could optimize the entire expression to 23 and have no evaluation at all at runtime. It could evaluate the right side of arithmetic operators before the left side, except for subtraction. It could randomly decide at runtime which to evaluate first.

Ignoring that, for an explanation of how to manually do the work, see ["How Lazy Evaluation Works in Haskell"](https://hackhands.com/lazy-evaluation-works-haskell/).

---

But how to manually figure it out is not the main point of this answer. Your question was what evaluation order Haskell would actually use, so this answer loosely intends to tell you the evaluation order your program uses when compiled with the compiler of your choice (ignoring some caveats that don't matter for basic understanding of evaluation order).

With some work, we can have Haskell tell us what order it evaluates in. If you're in school, you probably want to learn how to find the evaluation order manually without assistance so that you can do well on a test.

It's recommended that you only do this to check an answer you're confident in. You can also use it if you get stuck, but you should only read up until the point that you're stuck to see what the next step is and to make an educated guess about *why* that's the next step so that you can begin to learn what the rules are by experimenting. This, in combination with the above linked article, will help quite a bit.

To do this, we can expand upon Jonas Duregård's answer by using `Debug.Trace`'s functions instead of `error`. `Debug.Trace`'s functions can output things *when* something starts or stops being evaluated, so they're quite appropriate here:

```hs
import Debug.Trace

-- Show result
r :: String -> Int -> Int
r nm n = trace ("Result of " ++ nm ++ " is " ++ show n) n

-- Show evaluation of Int -> Int -> Int function
f :: String -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int -> Int
f nm g a b = e nm $ g a b

-- Show evaluation of an Int
e :: String -> Int -> Int
e nm = r nm . trace ("Evaluating " ++ nm)

-- Show Int literal
i :: Int -> Int
i n = e (show n) n

multiply :: Int -> Int -> Int
multiply a b = e "multiply" $ (f "multiply's *" (*))
                              (e "multiply's a" a)
                              (e "multiply's b" b)

minus :: Int -> Int -> Int
minus a b = e "minus" $ (f "minus's -" (-))
                        (e "minus's a" a)
                        (e "minus's b" b)

minus2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
minus2 a b = e "minus2" $ (f "minus2's -" (-))
                          (e "minus2's b" b)
                          (e "minus2's a" a)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ minus2 (multiply (minus (i 3) (i 5)) (i 7)) (i 9)
```

Once you've solved the problem on paper, you can check your answer with [the results of the above code run on GHC](https://ideone.com/BjTZNQ#stderr). It tells you what evaluation order your code uses when compiled with GHC.

You can alternatively run this through the Haskell compiler of your choice.